# Android layout issue on x86 VM

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my app on Android x86 in VirtualBox, and I've hit a small but annoying problem. I've not had this problem before, when I had the VM at the tablet resolution I was mimicking. However, I'm now running the VM at and writing the app for a smaller (phone) resolution.  The problem is that the layout looks fine in eclipse and on the actual phone, but everything is shifted in the VM. The resolution and pixel density are supposed to be the same in all three cases, so I'm not sure what to do. The app still functions, but I would prefer the various views to be where they should and look correctly placed, instead of being shifted left and up. It's almost as if everything is drawn correctly in a subset of the screen. Thanks in advance for any help!